# How to clear cache on Sitecore 7.5 delivery server?

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore7.5

I have 2 CD servers using Sitecore 7.5 that have the actual Sitecore interfaces turned off.  Is there any way for me to clear the caches on the 2 CD servers?  I know that there is probably a way I could write code to do it, but I would be surprised that there is no way to do it out of the box.

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: If you're talking about html cache, publish any item should do the work, right? Assuming you have `publish:end` event with html cache clearer defined for your site.

Comment: Well, I did lots of publishing and republishing of certain content items.  And I am noticing that something that I would expect to be changed on the live site has not changed.  I can't figure out why.  So my next thought is to clear all of the Sitecore caches and see if that fixes it.

Comment: so you can't use the cache admin page /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx  ?

Comment: Make sure it is published, switch over to the web db and check the change is there.

Comment: Depending on what caching you would want to clear there a couple of options: 1. You could do set the caches in <site> tag in config and change cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" attributes. 2. Caching at a component level which can be modified - vary by data, device, login, parameters, query string and user. 3. Check out Sitecore Rocks, it also gives some options related to caching which might help.

Comment: A Recycle of IIS Application Pool, clears the cache.

Answer (score 0):

As @Marek mentioned, you have to have your html cache clearing specified for your site in the web.config.  Since you're trying to clear the cache on the CD servers, you have to have this defined in the `publish:end:remote` event vs the `publish:end` event.:

```xml
      <event name="publish:end:remote">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site>website</site>
            <site>YOUR SITE DEFINITION SITE NAME HERE</site>
          </sites>
        </handler>
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.RenderingParametersCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache" />
      </event>
```

Assuming you have a new site defined that is not the OOTB website site definition, you just have to put your name in where I have `YOUR SITE DEFINITION SITE NAME HERE` above and your cache should clear on a publish.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question that the OP posted. He wants to be able to manually clear the cache, while still having the /sitecore area of the site disabled.

Comment: Note, that if you are patching this setting, you also need to include a unique dummy attribute value for each additional entry otherwise it will just include the last one. I've used  `<site sitename="yourSiteName">yourSiteName</site>`

Comment: I didn't see that the OP requested how to clear the caches manually.  In fairness, he didn't directly request how to do it automatically either.  I presented the automatic way.  If you want to manually clear the cache, you can cheat by adding a space to your web.config and deploy it to restart the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't be a neat solution but could fit into your specific requirment.

- Take Sitecore's page for manual cache refresh. Website\sitecore\admin\cache.aspx
- Copy into specific directory where you want this page to be accesses from.
- Decomile Sitecore's dll 'Sitecore.sitecore.admin.CacheAdmin' and remove Sitecore authentication requirment from it and create your custom class.
- Use that custom class in cache.aspx which you placed in CD server.