# Sitecore returns incorrect items in multi server farm

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a Sitecore website deployed in multi server environment. When I make some changes to Sitecore items sometimes they are shown correctly, but sometimes it shows old data.

I understand that sitecore caches items, but it sometimes showing wrong data and sometime its fine. If its caching it should always be same data at least.

For example:
Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.TextByDomain("MyDictionary", "Category");

Sometimes it returns correct data sometimes it shows wrong data i.e. the one before I changed to item.

I am using Sitecore 8.0

Comment: Firstly are you having this issue only with this rendering/sublayout? it sounds like you need to ensure to check the "vary by data" parameter

Comment: is your issue only with the dictionary items ?

Answer (score 1):

Items get cached on the individual servers in memory, and these are not cleared unless you activate event queues. Further content might be cached in the output cache, which needs to be cleared after you publish.

[Here is a guide on how to activate event queues](http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/07/sitecore-event-queue-scalability-king.html) and [here is also a good description](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sitecore-event-queues/)

[Here is how to make your sites clear output cache after publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436175/how-to-clear-cache-on-sitecore-7-5-delivery-server)

Comment: Thanks for the links. If I put host entry in the hosts file for server 1 it works for fine. And if I remove it same fluctuation happens. So the problem is with server 2. But my question is how to identify. My web.confg on both CD is same, scabilitysettings.config are same (both have eventqueue entry). How can I identify whats wrong with server 2 ? thanks

Comment: Hi Saad, It might be that one item is cached on one server and the other don't. To fix it correctly you will need to 1. setup event queues and 2. ensure that html cache clearing is set up correctly. You can do that by following the description in the above links.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jens for your help. The links really helped me with my understanding of Sitecore farm.

But the issue turned out to be rather silly. For some reason on one content delivery server Application Pool account didn't had permission on the virtual directory.